# Cannot set MTU for Network interface in FreeNAS-11.3-U3.2 Web Interface

Tags: networking, freebsd, truenas

I'm trying to set the MTU value for my network interface in FreeNAS-11.3-U3.2 to 9000.

However, when I select the interface to EDIT in the WebUI, enter `9000` for the MTU field, then click "APPLY", I get the following error.

```
VALLIDATION ERRORS:
[EINVAL] interface_update.aliases.0: The network 192.168.1.0/24 is already in use by another interface.
```

> NOTE:
> I previously was unable to configure the interface via the WEBUI when setting the IP (resulting in the same error), and successfully set the interface via the freenas console.

Is there a setting I need to change in order to enable network configuration (specifically MTU) for network interfaces in the WEBUI?

Or, alternatively, how can I set the MTU value?

---

UPDATE: looks like I was able to set mtu=9000 via the shell, but isn't persistent after reboot.

```
# update interface mtu
ifconfig em0 10.20.110.2 mtu 9000

# NAS to {OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE}
# ping -D -s 8972 {OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE}
PING {OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE} ({OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE}): 8972 data bytes
8980 bytes from {OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE}: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.538 ms
8980 bytes from {OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE}: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.221 ms
8980 bytes from {OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE}: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.557 ms
8980 bytes from {OTHER MACHINE WITH 10GbE}: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.310 ms
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the MTU on the interface you’re connected to?

Comment: I've tried both, from the interface I'm connected to and from an interface that's different, both result in the same error.

Comment: What other interface was configured with that network?

Comment: I have three interfaces, 2 connected at the moment, set to ips 192.168.1.(20|21|22) with same netmask.  As mentioned I wasn't initially able to configure these IPs through the WebUI (with the same error), and ended up setting them directly through the console.

Comment: Do you have any bridge or LACP aggregation configured?

Comment: Thanks, no, I don't have any LACP configured, these are 2 separate interfaces.  I did notice poking around that when I tried, `/etc/rc.d/netif restart INTERFACE` I get the message, "_Cannot 'restart' netif.  Set netif_enable to YES in /etc/rc.conf or use 'onerestart' instaed of 'restart'".